# Select values by not contains value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have next table test_table:

```
loginId reportType
  1      2
  1      1
  2      2
  2      1
  3      1
  4      1
  5      1
```

I need to extract all id's which doesn't have report type 2 (which means id's:3,4,5)
but for some reason next query returns all id's:

```
select loginId from test_table
where reportType = 1 and reportType != 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT LOGINID FROM TEST_TABLE AS C WHERE C.REPORTTYPE=1
  EXCEPT 
SELECT LOGINID FROM TEST_TABLE AS C WHERE C.REPORTTYPE=2
```

Answer (score 1):

There are same ids with reportType = 1 and reportType = 2. For example loginId = 1. This is why your query returns you all the ids.

Let me clarify this a bit. The database applies the WHERE condition to each row of the data source. Thus, the steps while performing your query were:

1. Line 1: loginId = 1 reportType = 2 -- false => no need to return
2. Line 2: loginId = 1 reportType = 1 -- true => return loginId = 1
   ..
3. Line 4: loginId = 2 reportType = 2 -- true => return loginId = 2
   ... and so on

You need to use "not exists" clause in order to filter those out

```
select loginId 
  from test_table tt
 where not exists (select 1 from test_table tt2 where tt.loginId = tt2.loginId and reportType = 2);
```

Note, I've changed the sub-query conditions